# Integer Inequality for Repeating Intervals

Tags: inequality, integers, interval-arithmetic

I've tried poking around a little bit for a more formal way of asking this question, but can't seem to find anything. So you'll forgive my ignorance and (undoubtedly) sloppy notation/ terminology. Let's say I have a repeating discontinuous interval:

$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^N [a + n(b+c),a+n(2b+c)], \qquad a,b,c,N\in\mathbb{N}^+
$$

For the sake of example, take $a=100, b=200, c=500$, then the interval is:

$$
[800,1000] \cup [1500,1700] \cup [2200,2400] \cup \cdots
$$

Now, take some arbitrary $x\in\mathbb{N}^+$. Is there a closed-form way to find:

1. Whether $x$ lies in any of these intervals, and if so;
2. Which interval, $n$, does it lie in?

I've tried fiddling with integer inequalities, which leads me to the following. For $x$ to be valid, we have

$$
a + n(b+c) \leq x \leq a + n(2b+c)
$$

and after a bit of rearranging:

$$
\frac{x-a}{b+c} \geq n \geq \frac{x-a}{2b+c}
$$

The range will contain an integer if $x$ is valid, otherwise it won't, e.g. let $x=900$:

$$
\frac{8}{7} \geq n \geq \frac{8}{9}
$$

and we have $n=1$. Contrastingly, let $x=1200$:

$$
\frac{11}{7} \geq n \geq \frac{11}{9}
$$

which has no solutions for $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$.

**But this appears to fall down**. Let $a=100, b=500, c=1500$, such that we get:

$$
[2100,2600]\cup[4100,4600]\cup[6100,6600]\cup[8100,8600]\cup\cdots
$$

Then selecting $x=7200$,we have:

$$
\frac{71}{20} \geq n \geq \frac{71}{25} \quad\implies\quad 3.55 \geq n \geq 2.84
$$

and so $n=3$ is a valid solution. But the third interval is $[6100,6600]$, within which $x$ clearly does not reside. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For $x>3$, let $a = x-3$, $n = b = c = 1$.  For $x = 3$, choose $a = n = b = c = 1$.  For $x = 1$ and $x = 2$, there is no such interval because the smallest lower bound of your interval is $1+1\cdot (1+1) = 3$.

Comment: I don't really follow -- I asked whether there was a closed-form solution to this for arbitrary $x$ rather than working through a particular example.